# when does prepareForSegue get called?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So here is my situation, I have two view controllers: viewControllerA and tableViewControllerB. On my viewControllerA, I have a button. And when it gets pressed, it will call

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toControllerB", sender: self)
```

moreover, I wrote a prepareforSegue function that looks like the following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "toControllerB"){

        var controllerB = segue.destinationViewController as tableViewControllerB
        controllerB.event = self.event
    }
```

And in my tableViewControllerB I have a function looks like the following

```
var event = nil
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    self.viewDidLoad()
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("controllerBCell") as? ControllerBCell ?? ControllerBCell()
    //some code
    print(event)
    return cell

}
```

And when I run my app, it seems like this tableview function gets called before the prepareforSegue function in ControllerA. And thus the "event" variable is nil. Therefore, I am wondering is it possible to call prepareforSegue function before this tableview function in controllerB?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling self.viewDidLoad()? generally it's called automatically. Is it your own function?

Comment: The table view functions should not be being called before prepareForSegue. prepareForSegue is called after the new controller is instantiated, but before the view is loaded. You should not be calling viewDidLoad yourself inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Are you sure that self.event is not nil at the time of your prepareForSegue function?

Comment: you guys are right, self.event is nil at the time of prepareForSegue. My bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chain is something like this.

1. First prepareForSegue is called
2. Then viewDidLoad is called
3. Then cellForRowAtIndexPath is called

I guess the problem is your line

```
self.viewDidLoad()
```

This function is called automatically. I just tried rest of the code at my end and it works fine.

Comment: Is  prepareForSegue called before performSegue(withIdentifier:__) ? or is it the other way round?